# Parellelize a thread execution in Java

Tags: java

What I´m trying to do is best explained with the next imagen.

[image: explanation]

So I want to create a new thread to call the method send mail (T2) in the same time that the original thread (T1) finish the method execution and return the boolean.

I tried to do this, but It´s doesn´t work. I don´t know what I´m doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 for using an image ;)

Comment: I don't quite get your question. What doesn't work? If I understand you correctly, you want to start `sendEmailThread` and then immediately return the boolean without waiting for success, right?

Comment: @John omg, I didn't see he was calling `run()` instead of `start()` - :)

Answer (score 5):

You need to start the thread by calling `sendEmailThread.start();`

Comment: Thanks, I´m trying and I´ll tell you ;)